# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type when fetching content

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am fetching content from my cms and passing data to my component:

```
const activeBreakdownContent = cmsData?.activeBreakdownContent;
 data: [
    <HomeHeader
      dynamicHeroItems={filteredCarouselItems}
      activeBreakdownContent={activeBreakdownContent}
    />,
```

I get the error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ activeBreakdownDescription?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownHeader?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownIcon?: any; activeBreakdownImage?: any; }'

My HomeHeader component is:

```
interface HomeHeaderProps {
  dynamicHeroItems: MobileApiContract.Models.CMSEnrichmentModels.DynamicHeroCarouselItem[];
  activeBreakdownContent: MobileApiContract.Models.CMSEnrichmentModels.Homepage['activeBreakdownContent'];
}
    const HomeHeader = ({
      activeBreakdownContent: {
        activeBreakdownHeader,
        activeBreakdownDescription,
        activeBreakdownIcon,
        activeBreakdownImage,
      },
      dynamicHeroItems,
    }: HomeHeaderProps) => {
      ...
    
      if (isActiveBreakdown && EnableHomepageETA) {
        return (
          <RescueMeHero
            title={activeBreakdownHeader || 'backup tutle'}
            body={activeBreakdownDescription || 'backup tutle'}
            image={activeBreakdownImage}
            icon={activeBreakdownIcon}
          />
        );
      }
```

MobileApiContract:

```
    activeBreakdownContent: {
  activeBreakdownDescription?: string;
  activeBreakdownHeader?: string;
  activeBreakdownIcon?: BaseImageModel;
  activeBreakdownImage?: BaseImageModel;
};
```

How can I pass data to my component to keep typescript happy?

Comment: Wrap a ```if (activeBreakdownContent)``` around it. Maybe remove undefined from the interface and use the ? syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue lies with the fact you're trying to destrcutre the code before the object is defined.

##### 1. Fall back to a definite value;

```js
const activeBreakdownContent = cmsData?.activeBreakdownContent ?? {};
 data: [
    <HomeHeader
      dynamicHeroItems={filteredCarouselItems}
      activeBreakdownContent={activeBreakdownContent}
    />,
```

##### 2. Don't render that component if you don't have a value

```js
const activeBreakdownContent = cmsData?.activeBreakdownContent;

if (!activeBreakdownContent) {
  // do something
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

...
 data: [
    <HomeHeader
      dynamicHeroItems={filteredCarouselItems}
      activeBreakdownContent={activeBreakdownContent}
    />,
```

##### 3. Don't destructure so soon

```js
interface HomeHeaderProps {
  dynamicHeroItems: MobileApiContract.Models.CMSEnrichmentModels.DynamicHeroCarouselItem[];
  activeBreakdownContent: MobileApiContract.Models.CMSEnrichmentModels.Homepage['activeBreakdownContent'];
}
    const HomeHeader:React.FC<HomeHeaderProps> = ({
      activeBreakdownContent,
      dynamicHeroItems,
    }) => {
      ...

    // Check it exists
    if (!activeBreakdownContent) {
      return <div>No content yet</div>
    }
    // now destructure
    const {
        activeBreakdownHeader,
        activeBreakdownDescription,
        activeBreakdownIcon,
        activeBreakdownImage,
      } = activeBreakdownContent;
    
      if (isActiveBreakdown && EnableHomepageETA) {
        return (
          <RescueMeHero
            title={activeBreakdownHeader || 'backup tutle'}
            body={activeBreakdownDescription || 'backup tutle'}
            image={activeBreakdownImage}
            icon={activeBreakdownIcon}
          />
        );
      }
```